# Tcl and Couch DB

Tags: tcl, couchdb

I need to write log messages from TCL to a local CouchDB; I need to use both of these technologies and I can't change either. I have come up with the code below, but it is quite slow. Are there any suggestions on how it could be improved?

The formatted JSON containing the record and database name are passed into this proc, whilst for better or worse the username and password are global variables.

```
# Name: WriteToLocalCouch
    # Description:
    #     Write to a Couch Database on localhost. Username and password are global variables
    #   Read from the config file.
    # Parameters:
    #     DbName - Database name
    #   JsonData - Formatted JSON to write to the database
    # Returns:
    #     True if the write was sucessful, otherwise false
    proc WriteToLocalCouch { DbName JsonData } {
    
         global COUCH_USER
         global COUCH_PASSWORD
         
         set result [exec curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5984/$DbName -d $JsonData -u $COUCH_USER:$COUCH_PASSWORD -s]
         
         if { [string first {"ok":true} $result] < 0 } {
             puts {Error Writing to Db}
            return 0
         }
         
         return 1
    }
```

Comment: Use the native [`http` client](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm) and JSON parser from [tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/toc.md)?

Comment: What about [`couchdbtcl`](https://github.com/ray2501/couchdbtcl)?